# Python array literal syntax sugar similar to Perl and Ruby

Tags: python, python-2.x

#### Background

- Python (version 2.7.2)

#### Problem

- You want to specify an array in your code.
- You want to use the 'syntax sugar' available in Ruby and Perl.
- You are a fanatic about readable code but also saving keystrokes.

#### Solution

- Python Triple-quoted string
- Python splitlines
- Python list comprehension

#### Pitfalls

- The solution may look ugly or un-Python-ish

#### Question

Are there any refactorings, suggestions or comments on this approach?

```
### ********************
## setup an array using append
ary_names = []
ary_names.append('alpha')
ary_names.append('bravo')
ary_names.append('charlie')
ary_names.append('delta')
ary_names.append('echo')

### ********************
## setup an array using triple-quoted string
ary_names = [
  item.strip() for item in  
  """

  alpha
  bravo
  charlie
  delta
  echo

  """
  .splitlines()
  if(not item.strip()=='')
]

"""
Here is a ruby example for comparison

ary_names = %w[
  alpha
  bravo
  charlie
  delta
  echo      
]
"""
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call `split` with no arguments, it will split on any whitespace and drop any empty elements. Knowing that, it's as simple as this:

```
ary_names = """
    alpha
    bravo
    charlie
    delta
    echo
""".split()
```

If you have only five short elements, you may want to put them all on one line:

```
ary_names = 'alpha bravo charlie delta echo'.split()
```

Of course, you'd only want to do that if it fits easily on one line.

Comment: its worth noting this won't worth string tokens including multiple words, unlike OP's answerr

Answer (score 3):

This will work as written. You could shorten it slightly by replacing

```
if(not item.strip()=='')
```

with

```
 if item.strip()
```

You're also calling strip twice, you could skip that with:

```
array_names = [i for i in map(str.strip, my_big_string.splitlines()) if i]
```

I would avoid inlining the actual constants in the list comprehension tool - that's bad for readability if it's not sitting on the outermost outline level.

On the philosophical level, I'm ambivalent. I hate all the quotes etc  too, but  this only works for strings, so it's not a general purpose idiom.  You could extend it with exec or eval to get non-string values, but that's a whole big can o' worms :)

Comment: `strip` isn't a top-level function; you'd have to use `str.strip` or `lambda s: s.strip()` if you want to pass it to `map`.